# handling modal form within the normal form in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, bootstrap-modal

I have got 2 forms a normal form and inside that a modal which is also a form, while filling the normal form user can click a button where modal pop's up and he can fill the form inside the modal. I have n issue where when i click the save after filling both modal form and normal form,i can only find the data of the normal form in my controller, the data which i filled in modal cannot be found, can any one help me in this where when i click save a function gets called in controller and i should be able to see both normal form data and modal form data.

Comment: can you please show $scope value that you are getting from the controller